# Combine multiple columns into one based on values from a column

Tags: sql, oracle

**DATA:**

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+
| WEEK_NO| Week1| Week2| Week3|Week4 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
|      1 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |
|      2 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |
|      3 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |
|      4 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |
+--------+------+------+------+------+
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+-------------+
| WEEK_NO| Week1| Week2| Week3|Week4 |COLUMN NEEDED|
+--------+------+------+------+------+-------------+
|      1 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |    0.5      |
|      2 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |    0.2      |
|      3 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |    0.3      |
|      4 |  0.5 |  0.2 |  0.3 |0.4   |    0.4      |
+--------+------+------+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: It would end up with nasty case statements.... Eg: `CASE WHEN WEEK_NO = 1 then WEEK1`.. But why would the data be saved this way? Perhaps a quiz!

Comment: This sounds as if you should rather think about normalizing your data model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  
i agree with your point , but somehow the data is coming in the above mentioned structure and cant be changed at the source

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN WEEK_NO = 1 THEN Week1
         WHEN WEEK_NO = 2 THEN Week2
         WHEN WEEK_NO = 3 THEN Week3
         WHEN WEEK_NO = 4 THEN Week4
       END AS "COLUMN NEEDED"
FROM   yourtable
```

Or use [`Decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

```
Select DECODE (WEEK_NO, 1, Week1, 
                        2, Week2, 
                        3, Week3, 
                        4, Week4) 
From yourtable
```

Consider changing your table structure

Comment: I tried this ,but it doesnt work in PL/SQL procedure , below is what i tried
CODE TRIED :
select case substr(to_char(WEEK_NO,seed_number),-2,2)
when '01' then  W1
when '02' then  W2
when '03' then  W3
.                             .
.                             .
when '49' then  W49
when '50' then  W50
when '51' then  W51
when '52' then  W52
END as WEEK_COEFF 
FROM TABLE

Comment: ERROR :
ORA-06550: line 22, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "01" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @Abhijeetsingh - Post the query you are using

Comment: select case substr(to_char(WEEK_NO,'999999'),-2,2)
when '01' then  W1
when '02' then  W2
when '03' then  W3
when '04' then  W4
when '05' then  W5
when '06' then  W6
when '07' then  W7
when '08' then  W8
when '09' then  W9
when '10' then  W10
when '11' then  W11
.....
when '46' then  W46
when '47' then  W47
when '48' then  W48
when '49' then  W49
when '50' then  W50
when '51' then  W51
when '52' then  W52
END as WEEK_COEFF 
FROM TABLE

Answer (score 0):

The duplication of data in the rows of the original table is highly suspicious. Obviously we know nothing about the purpose of this structure but it does seem like a failure of data modelling. Applying [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) would give...

```
create table weeks (
    week_no number primary key
    , week_coeff number not null )
/
```

So the query would be:

```
select week_no
       , week_coeff as column_needed
from weeks
/
```

If this seems too simplistic then please explain the business rules you are modelling.

---

> "but somehow the data is coming in the above mentioned structure and cant be changed at the source ."

Of course it *can* be changed, it's just a data structure. But office politics are office politics. Good luck with building horrible, brittle code.

Comment: got your point , but somehow the data is coming in the above mentioned structure and cant be changed at the source .